# String quoting issues with sql using ST_PointFromText in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I've been banging my head against this for a while, and am seeking some insight into what I'm doing wrong. I have the following snippet of code:

```
params = [PlaneRep.hex, PlaneRep.squawk, PlaneRep.flight, PlaneRep.isMetric, 
    PlaneRep.mlat, PlaneRep.altitude, PlaneRep.speed, PlaneRep.vert_rate,
    dbdate, dbtime, PlaneRep.track, coordinates, PlaneRep.messages]
sql = '''
    INSERT into planereports (hex, squawk, flight, "isMetric", "isMLAT", altitude, speed, vert_rate, date_of_report, time_of_report, bearing, report_location, messages_sent)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, ST_PointFromText(%s, 4326), %s);'''
print(cur.mogrify(sql, params))
cur.execute(sql,params)
```

which yields the following error:

```
b'\n\t\tINSERT into planereports (hex, squawk, flight, "isMetric",     "isMLAT", altitude, speed, vert_rate, date_of_report, time_of_report,     bearing, report_location, messages_sent)\n\t\tVALUES (\'7c6d33\', \'3241\',     \'VOZ850  \', true, false, 9563, 822, 546.2016, \'2015-10-21\', \'04:32:41\', 235, ST_PointFromText(\'POINT(150.464266 -34.754929)\', 4326), 133);'
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "./jsonfiddling.py", line 92, in <module>
logToDB(dbconn, plane) 
File "./jsonfiddling.py", line 34, in logToDB
 cur.execute(sql,params)
 psycopg2.ProgrammingError: function st_pointfromtext(unknown, integer)    does not exist
LINE 3: ...63, 822, 546.2016, '2015-10-21', '04:32:41', 235, ST_PointFr...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your PostGIS is not being detected.

Can you verify you can do:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

If you used geodjango or ruby (ruby I know for sure is a case), they install PostGIS in a schema called "postgis" instead of public, so if that's the case, you may need to add that to your database search_path and also make sure the account you are connecting with has access to that schema.

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path="$user",public,postgis;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA postgis TO public;
```

Comment: postgres=# SELECT postgis_full_version();

Looks like you're right -

ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT postgis_full_version();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I'm using fedora22, and postgis is definitely installed. I had to create the postgis extension on that database for it to work - now I have a completely separate problem, but that's for another day....